# Should URLs with UTF8 characters be encoded in HTML?

Tags: html, url, links, url-encoding

I'm thinking of names and stuff containing accented characters.

E.g.is there a difference between:

```
<a href="http://example.com/thing?name=forêt">link</a>
```

and

```
<a href="http://example.com/thing?name=for%C3%AAt">link</a>
```

?

Do browsers handle these the same? Or is there some compelling reason to encode these links?

Answer (score 5):

> Do browsers handle these the same?

Yes, all (modern) *browsers* handle these the same. In that all (modern) browsers implicitly URL encode (ie. percent-encode) the URL if you don't explicitly encode this yourself in the HTML source.

In both cases, the browser will implicitly request the percent-encoded URL when a user clicks the link. Select "Copy link address" from the browser's context menu and you copy the percent-encoded URL in both cases. Reading the `href` attribute of both links using JavaScript returns the percent-encoded URL.

In fact, I believe HTML5 allows unencoded unicode characters:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19542940/369434

A potential problem might just be "old browsers". How old I don't know. But "old" might just be too old to worry about. (?)

Answer (score 1):

W3C says URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set. You will need to convert those characters to something. People often replace unsafe characters with their % encoded form. A percent-encoded reference can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Here is there reference: 
http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html

Comment: Yes, I know the recommendation. My question is more like is there a practical difference? AFAIK browsers can handle the unencoded form in my example just as well.

Comment: "People often replace unsafe characters with % symbol." - you mean, _invalid characters are percent-encoded_.

Comment: W3schools is NOT W3C.

Comment: The link to W3schools is just for the % encoded reference chart. The reference at the bottom of my answer is directly to the W3C URI recommendations overview. Sorry for any confusion.